# Amazon S3 & EC2 for hosting?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a little dot com site, personal portfolio, running HTML w/ CSS right now. I'm thinking of eventually running something like node.js w/ a custom CMS. But I'm paying over $110 a year for hosting when I use about .5 gigs of bandwidth a month & just a few domains I don't need.

Will EC2 with my own Server be cheaper on a micro instance? Not to mention nerdy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cheaper but, only by a little (except while your in the 1st year of trial service where some things are totally free).   After the first year its $85 for a 3-yr micro instance (or $54 for 1/yr) with the following:

```
613 MB memory
Up to 2 EC2 Compute Units (for short periodic bursts)
EBS storage only
32-bit or 64-bit platform
I/O Performance: Low
API name: t1.micro
```

Comment: It's a lot cheaper $85 for 3 years! How much bandwidth cap?

Comment: The 1 and 3 years prices are for reservation only does not include use. It entitles you to discounted instance price - so you will pay reservation fee ($82 for 3 years) and discounted usage fee - $61.32 each year which gives $265.96 for 3 years (reservation + usage).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed cheaper, and if you go small enough it's free for the first year (if you only have one instance).

Getting node.js to run on ec2 is a bit interesting but it can be done (I've done it). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well - micro instance is 2 cents per hour which gives 365*24*0.02 = 173$. Stay with your current hosting if you don't have problem with reliability there.

Comment: That's because Node.Js would always be running?  What about static HTML ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether Node.js will be running. You receive a running virtual machine. And I assume you want your site available 24/7. But with the reserved instance it will indeed be a bit cheaper, but you also pay for io, disk storage and well everything.

Comment: gotcha. I thought it was more of "on demand" type of hosting... pay for what you use.

Comment: thats the price for "daily usage" without having a 1 year contract.  its cheaper with a contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check price for other cloud providers with [**cloudorado.com**](http://www.cloudorado.com/).